# Parse JSON using recursive and for loop

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON to parse. I'm trying to use recursive method here.The current JSON has a structure similar to the bottom one

```
Item 01
 SubItem 01
  InnerSubItem 01

Item 02
 SubItem 01
  InnerSubItem 01
```

Using the function I created, I'm able to parse only the first set (Contents under Item 01). The code doesn't comes back to the loop when is condition is false

Code used

```js
$.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/6atbz', function(data) {
  repeat(data, data.layers);
})

function repeat(data, x) {
  var layer = data.layers.reverse()
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    name = x[i].name
    console.log(name)
    if (x[i].layers.length > 0) {
      repeat(data, x[i].layers)
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: JSON is like of native in javascript. u can simply use JSON.parse(data) to parse json data to js object.

Answer (score 1):

Your code breaks when the object doesn't have a `layers` property. You should check for its existence before checking for `length`.

e.g.

```
if (x[i].layers && x[i].layers.length > 0)
```

Fixed code:

```js
$.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/6atbz', function(data) {
  repeat(data, data.layers);
})

function repeat(data, x) {
  var layer = data.layers.reverse();
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    name = x[i].name;
    console.log(name);
    if (x[i].layers && x[i].layers.length > 0) {
      repeat(data, x[i].layers);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

On a side note, you don't seem to be using the reversed array and are unnecessarily passing `data` each time you call `repeat`. You could probably write something like this instead (reverse the array if you need to):

```js
$.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/6atbz', function(data) {
  repeat(data);
})

function repeat(data) {
  if (!data || !data.layers)
    return;

  var x = data.layers;
  for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    name = x[i].name;
    console.log(name);
    repeat(x[i]);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```